# "You" reference

Tags: complex-sentences

***when something is written after I said then full stop. can you please explain who said to whom? I don't understand "you" reference. It confuses me. for example, in the below example I have bold that sentence.***

> He continued to look at me, his gaze empty, distant. “Don’t you want to see the chapel?” he asked.
>
> I could see he didn’t approve of my decision. He thinks I’m weak, cowardly, unable to fight for what I want. Even without a kiss, the princess is transformed into a frog.
>
> “Remember yesterday?” I said. “**You ended our conversation in the bar because you didn’t want to argue with me. Now when I do the same thing, you criticize me.**”
>
> The old man watched our discussion impassively. He was probably happy that something was actually happening, there in a place where all the mornings, all the afternoons, and all the nights were the same.
>
> “The door to the church is open,” he said, speaking to the old man. “If you want some money, we can give you some. But she wants to see the church.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in that paragraph is what the second speaker ('I') said. 'You' is the man she is speaking to.

The convention in writing dialogue is to start a new paragraph for each speaker's words. The full stop after 'said' is because her next words are a new sentence. The last paragraph works the same way.